# What do you call the "group that this group is a subgroup of"?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

This may be a really silly question, but I'm struggling to Google it - feels like it ought to be quite a simple...

But say I have two groups $G$ and $H$, with $H$ a subgroup of $G$.

Is there a way I can say in *one* word, what $G$ is to $H$?

i.e. $G$ is a <something> group for $H$.

My instinct says "supergroup", but I just made that up and it doesn't seem like it's standard terminology.

"Containing group", "Parent group", "Bigger group"? None of those seem right.

This is in the context of naming variables in a program, where I'd like it be as clear as possible... of course if I was writing it I would just say "$G$ is a group which has $H$ as a subgroup"

Comment: Overgroup. Do not use "supergroup" since "super" is heavily used in the context of super-manifolds.

Comment: If $H$ is a normal subgroup, you might want to look at Group Extensions, so $G$ is a group extension of $N$ if there is a short exact sequence $1\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 1$ that is if $Q\cong G/N$. Thus, if you are looking at abelian groups, I think group extension might be a good word, but as for a specific word for the general case, I don't know of a term.

Comment: I say parent group, but it doesn't matter as long as you make your intentions clear in your writing.

Comment: Perhaps also "ambient group", by analogy with spaces?

Comment: You could say $H$ embeds into $G$, and write $H\hookrightarrow G$. Subgroups and embedded groups are the same in the meaning that every embdded group corresponds to a subgroup. If $H=G$, the embedding can be the inclusion map $i:H\hookrightarrow G$ which sends each $h \in H$ to itself. If $H$ is not a subset of $G$ and embeds into $G$, say with $\phi: H\hookrightarrow G$, so $H$ and $\phi(H)$ are isomorphic.

Comment: It is overgroup here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup

Comment: (Overgroup naturally coming from German terminology here, since subgroup in German is "untergruppe", "undergroup" in English.)

Comment: $x >y $ can be written as $y<x$ . $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ . Then, you can say, $G$ is a group containing the subgroup $H$. Though it doesn't sound good, no need to worry as long as it is clear from the context. Even you can use the symbol $H\le G$ .

Comment: I use 'parent group'.

Comment: @prets Exactly. In Germany, nearby Oberwolfach (a center for mathematics) there is the village "Untergruppenbach". Next to "Obergruppenbach", I guess.